# Разворачивающийся список с изменением картинки

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, ajax

```js
var i=0;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".vakan").hide();
    $(".vakan li:odd").css("background-color", "#efefef");
    $("h3 span").click(function(){
 i++;
 $(this).parent().next().slideToggle();
 if (i==1){
  
 }
 if (i==2){
     i=0;
 }
    });
});
```

```css
.box {
    margin: 0px auto;
    background: #fff;
    /* border: 1px solid #d1d1d1; */
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: Georgia, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    /* -webkit-border-radius: 5px; */
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #ddd;
    /* -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #ddd; */
}
.box h3 {
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #efefef 0%,#e0e0e0 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #efefef),color-stop(1, #e0e0e0));
    border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
    color: #c1c1c1;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #fff;
    margin:0;
}
.box h3 span {
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.box h3 span:hover {
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #a1eeff;
}
.vakan {
    padding: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin:0;
}
.vakan li {
    font-size: 13px;
    list-style-type: square;
    list-style-position: inside;
    color: #a1a1a1;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
<div class="box">
    <h3>Список №1<span class="expand">+</span></h3>
    <ul class="vakan">
 <li>Пункт №1</li>
 <li>Пункт №2</li>
 <li>Пункт №3</li>
 <li>Пункт №4</li>
 <li>Пункт №5</li>
 <li>Пункт №6</li>
 <li>Пункт №7</li>
 <li>Пункт №8</li>
 <li>Пункт №9</li>
 <li>Пункт №10</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

как сделать вместо + картинку стрелочка вниз, а при нажатии и раскрытии чтобы появлялась стрелочка вверх и наоборот

Answer (score 1):

Добавляем в `css` класс `active`, в котором будет стрелка. Из `html` убираем `+`. В скрипте - если меню активно, то убираем класс, если неактивно - добавляем класс.

```js
var i=0;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".vakan").hide();    
    var menuActive = false;
  
    $(".vakan li:odd").css("background-color", "#efefef");
  
    $("h3 span").click(function(){            
      if (menuActive)
        $(this).removeClass('active');
      else
        $(this).addClass('active');
      
        menuActive = !menuActive;
     $(this).parent().next().slideToggle();
    });
});
```

```css
.box {
    margin: 0px auto;
    background: #fff;
    /* border: 1px solid #d1d1d1; */
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: Georgia, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    /* -webkit-border-radius: 5px; */
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #ddd;
    /* -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #ddd; */
}
.box h3 {
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #efefef 0%,#e0e0e0 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #efefef),color-stop(1, #e0e0e0));
    border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
    color: #c1c1c1;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #fff;
    margin:0;
}
.box h3 span {
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.box h3 span:hover {
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #a1eeff;
}
.vakan {
    padding: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin:0;
}
.vakan li {
    font-size: 13px;
    list-style-type: square;
    list-style-position: inside;
    color: #a1a1a1;
    padding: 5px;
}

/******** Добавлено *********/
.box h3 span:before {
  content: "▼";
  /* если картинку вставить то
   content: url("http://s1.iconbird.com/ico/0612/GooglePlusInterfaceIcons/w128h1281338911632directionaldown.png");
    position: absolute;
    left: 14px;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
  
  */
}

.box h3 span.active:before {
  content: "▲";
  /* если картинку вставить то
   content: url("http://s1.iconbird.com/ico/0612/GooglePlusInterfaceIcons/w128h1281338911586directionalup.png");
    position: absolute;
    left: 14px;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
  
  */
}
/******** Добавлено *********/
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
<div class="box">
    <h3>Список №1<span class="expand"></span></h3>
    <ul class="vakan">
 <li>Пункт №1</li>
 <li>Пункт №2</li>
 <li>Пункт №3</li>
 <li>Пункт №4</li>
 <li>Пункт №5</li>
 <li>Пункт №6</li>
 <li>Пункт №7</li>
 <li>Пункт №8</li>
 <li>Пункт №9</li>
 <li>Пункт №10</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: как добавить картинку? я что-то пробую и не получается

Comment: @Aslero вместо `content: "▼";` и `content: "▲";`  пишите `content: url("какая-то картинка.jpg");` плюс придется добавить тогда `position: absolute;`, позицию слева, сверху и ширину/высоту картинки...... а у `.box h3` - отступ слева .....написал в комментарии в css ..........................кстати  вариант с `toggleClass` неплох тоже....я что-то не вспомнил что такой есть у jquery

Answer (score 0):

```js
var i=0;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".vakan").hide();
    $(".vakan li:odd").css("background-color", "#efefef");
    $("h3 span").click(function(){
 i++;
 //$(this).parent().next().slideToggle(0);
 $(this).parent().next().toggle();
    $(this).toggleClass("opened");
 if (i==1){
  
 }
 if (i==2){
     i=0;
 }
    });
});
```

```css
.box {
    margin: 0px auto;
    background: #fff;
    /* border: 1px solid #d1d1d1; */
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: Georgia, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    /* -webkit-border-radius: 5px; */
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #ddd;
    /* -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #ddd; */
}
.box h3 {
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #efefef 0%,#e0e0e0 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #efefef),color-stop(1, #e0e0e0));
    border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
    color: #c1c1c1;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #fff;
    margin:0;
}
.box h3 span {
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/56/Circle-icons-arrow-down.svg") no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
}
.box h3 span.opened {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.box h3 span:hover {
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #a1eeff;
}
.vakan {
    padding: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin:0;
}
.vakan li {
    font-size: 13px;
    list-style-type: square;
    list-style-position: inside;
    color: #a1a1a1;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
<div class="box">
    <h3>Список №1<span class="expand"></span></h3>
    <ul class="vakan">
 <li>Пункт №1</li>
 <li>Пункт №2</li>
 <li>Пункт №3</li>
 <li>Пункт №4</li>
 <li>Пункт №5</li>
 <li>Пункт №6</li>
 <li>Пункт №7</li>
 <li>Пункт №8</li>
 <li>Пункт №9</li>
 <li>Пункт №10</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: а можно убрать плавность появления li? чтобы сразу появилось

Comment: @Aslero - просто меняем slideToggle на toggle или ставим первый аргумент (длительность в мс) равный нулю.